# Two forms, one submit - Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I need to put two different forms on the same page and submit to send these forms at once.
Here is my action:

```
public function crearUsuarioAction()
{
    $newuser = new User();
    $formuser = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $newuser);
    $newdatos = new Datos();
    $formdatos = $this->createForm(new DatosType(), $newdatos);
    return $this->render('AtajoBundle:IngresarValores:crearusuario.html.twig', array('formuser' => $formuser->createView(), 'formdatos' => $formdatos->createView()));

}
```

In the template twig I have to show these two forms, with one submit button , and send all together to save after their corresponding tables. Form_start thought that if you could pass an array with two official forms but did not. here 's what we try:

```
    {% block content %}
{{ form_start(array(formuser, formdatos)) }}
{{ form_errors(array(formuser, formdatos)) }}
<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formuser.usuario) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formuser.usuario) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formuser.pass) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formuser.pass) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.empresa) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.empresa) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.cuit) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.cuit) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.localidad) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.localidad) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.calle) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.calle) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.altura) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.altura) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.areaTel) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.areaTel) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.telefono) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.telefono) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.areaCel) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.areaCel) }}</div>

<div class="contactotexto">{{ form_label(formdatos.celular) }}</div>
<div class="contactocampo">{{ form_widget(formdatos.celular) }}</div>

<div ><input class="contactosubmit" type="submit" id="submit"/></div>
{{ form_end(array(formuser, formdatos)) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You will need Javascript, or just one form: you can only submit one form at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a single form with both form types as properties?

Comment: look what it did. I have two entities , one with two fields: username and password, the other entity has the personal data of the user and these entities are related . Create two forms for each table. You see, in the controlodar I think the two forms to be shown in the template. In the template I show like a form with one submit button . but when the user submits the form and fed back into the controller , as I do to save the data accordingly ? ie save the username and password in the user table that call , and other personal data in the call data table . thanks

Comment: To follow up on @John's answer: the relationship between an entity and a form is not necessarily one-to-one - you can create an embedded form that can "include fields from many different objects" as specified in the docs. It sounds like your use case; you can read some more about embedded forms here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms

Comment: Maybe my answer was low quality, but I think it was justified. What he was trying to accomplish was the wrong approach. Thanks for follow up @Daragh.